# Deposits policy for holiday accommodation in Spain

Tags: accommodation, spain

I am in the process of booking an apartment somewhere in Spain and I've been told that I need to pay 30% of the total booking amount in advance to confirm the booking (fair enough) and after that I need to pay the remaining 70%, 15 days ***prior*** to arrival.

Having travelled in various countries across Europe, no one has asked for paying the full amount *before* I even reach the place.

My questions are:

1. Could they enforce this kind of payment in advance?
2. Is there something official from the ministry of tourism in Spain that regulates deposits that I could refer to?

Of course, any thoughts along these lines are more than welcome.

Comment: Which website have used to book your apartment?

Comment: Through their official website I asked for availability and then exchanging emails with the owner. Not through booking.com or such.

Comment: Well, I'm spanish and I believe that there isn't any regulation, so it's legal.

Comment: Thanks anyway. I decided to reject their policy and go for another option after all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's likely the apartment's individual policy.  I've seen places (not in Spain) that require the entire payment in advance as well.  A place I'm staying at in New Zealand in October required the full payment up front, which I paid back in April.

It's not the norm, but it does happen.

So in regards to your question:

1) It's not a case of them 'enforcing' it - it's your choice whether to stay there or not. If you do, you agree to their terms and conditions.  Same with any hotel's rules, whatever they might be, or however draconian they may seem.

2) This I'm not sure of.  Perhaps for rent, but not for holiday accommodation.  Fairly sure as long as they keep everything above board and don't scam you, they can do it.  However, make sure you have proof of requests for payment and proof of payment, just to ensure that there's a paper / electronic trail, should the need arise.